# After High Sierra, weird colours appear when waking up MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake, bug, high-sierra

[I'm coming from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/73nc9h/after_high_sierra_weird_colors_when_waking_up/) where they suggested me to post here. There seems to be many users with the same issue. Using a 13" MBP Early 2015.

After updating to macOS High Sierra I see weird colours for a brief moment each time I wake up the MBP. [Here is a GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8CND.jpg) to visualise it.
From what I read there, it seems to be an issue with the new Metal 2 graphic system. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Try also reporting this issue at: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Even I have the same issue here with the 13 inch 2015 MacBook

Comment: I just submitted it to Apple.

Comment: any luck resolving this?

Comment: @Matt not at all. Apple hasn’t released any fix.